# Customer/Material pair to count the occurences in the past 3 years and set the status flag. - aws redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with the following values

| date | customer name | material |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9/1/2020 | A | A1 |
| 8/1/2019 | A | A2 |
| 8/1/2018 | A | A2 |
| 9/2/2020 | B | A1 |
| 9/2/2019 | B | A2 |
| 9/2/2017 | B | A2 |

So the output should be something like, if I could see a customer with a material, who has an entry in the past 3 years, then the status flag should be Yes, other wise the status flag should be no.

| date | customer name | material | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/1/2020 | A | A1 | No |
| 8/1/2019 | A | A2 | Yes |
| 8/1/2018 | A | A2 | No |
| 9/2/2020 | B | A1 | No |
| 9/2/2019 | B | A2 | Yes |
| 9/2/2017 | B | A2 | No |

I was thinking about counting the given occurences of a customer/material pair, for the past 3 years, and check the count to set the status flag. But confused how I would use windowing function?

```
select customer_name, material, count(*) from table 
where datediff(year, date, current_date) <=3
group by customer_name, material
```

and then join this table, but I feel this approach is wrong as it does not account for rolling status.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions.  Probably the simplest is `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lag(date) over (partition by customer, material order by date) >= date - interval '3 year'
             then 'Yes' else 'No'
        end) as flag
from t
```